# Speeding up a large for loop using a parallel foreach

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm working on a project where I iterate over bins of the mouse genome and compute some overlaps using `GenomicRanges`/`rtracklayer`.  Bins are already computed in 150 base/position increments. For those who are not familiar, this means that for chromosomeY, which happens to be one of the shortest mouse chromosomes, there are approximately 106,000 bins and the larger chromosomes contain about 1,300,000 bins! **The goal here is to iterate through the bins, expand the range of the bins 100,000 positions in both directions, then figure out which genes overlap these window. I want to compute the distance from the center of the bin to the start of the genes contained within the expanded bin window.**

Okay so here's the code I've written to this point. It runs without error and computes exactly what I need. **The problem here is that it is slow and will take forever to iterate through 1M+ bins**.

```
progress <- function(w) {
  # just a function that prints out the window being processed
  cat(sprintf(paste0(as.character(Sys.time()), ": Window ", w, " completed!\n")))
}

extend <- function(x, upstream=0, downstream=0) {
# this will expand a `GenomicRanges` object range 
  if (any(strand(x) == "*"))
    warning("'*' ranges were treated as '+'")
  on_plus <- strand(x) == "+" | strand(x) == "*"
  new_start <- start(x) - ifelse(on_plus, upstream, downstream)
  new_end <- end(x) + ifelse(on_plus, downstream, upstream)
  ranges(x) <- IRanges(new_start, new_end)
  trim(x)
}


feature.overlap <- function(x, window, genes, extend.upstream=100000, extend.downstream=100000) {

  # # test case
  # x = chrY; window = 2668 ; genes = gene; extend.upstream = 100000 ; extend.downstream = 100000

  # extend window of signal in both directions
  x.window = extend(x[window], extend.upstream, extend.downstream) 
  names(x.window) <- window

  # compute signal window overlap with genes 
  overlaps <- subsetByOverlaps(genes, x.window)  

  if(length(overlaps) == 0){

    values <- data.frame(signal_window=names(x.window), 
                         signal_start=max(0, start(x.window)), 
                         signal_center=max(0, start(x.window)) + floor((width(x.window) - 1)/2), 
                         signal_end=end(x.window), 
                         signal_score=x.window$score,
                         symbol=NA, 
                         gene_id=NA,
                         gene_chr=NA,
                         gene_start=NA,
                         gene_end=NA,
                         gene_strand=NA)  

  } else {

    hits <- findOverlaps(x.window, genes)
    s.idx <- unique(subjectHits(hits))
    q.idx <- unique(queryHits(hits))    

    values <- data.frame(signal_window=names(x.window)[q.idx], 
                         signal_start=max(0, start(x.window)[q.idx]), 
                         signal_center=max(0, start(x.window)[q.idx]) + floor((width(x.window)[q.idx] - 1)/2), 
                         signal_end=end(x.window)[q.idx], 
                         signal_score=x.window$score[q.idx],
                         mcols(overlaps)[,c(2,1)], 
                         gene_chr=chrom(genes)[s.idx],
                         gene_start=ifelse(strand(genes)[s.idx] == '+', start(genes)[s.idx], end(genes)[s.idx]) ,
                         gene_end=end(genes)[s.idx],
                         gene_strand=strand(genes)[s.idx])

  }

  return(values)

}

# Import data
library(rtracklayer)
merged_wig <- import.wig('~/file/linked/below.wig', format='wig', genome='mm9')
merged_wig <- keepSeqlevels(merged_wig, paste0('chr', c(seq(1,19), 'X', 'Y')))
chrY <- merged_wig[seqnames(merged_wig) == 'chrY'] 

# Generate gene info needed for computing overlap
library(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm9.knownGene); library(Mus.musculus)
gene <- genes(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm9.knownGene)
values(gene) <- merge(values(gene), as.data.frame(org.Mm.egSYMBOL), by='gene_id', all.x=T)
gene <- keepSeqlevels(gene, paste0('chr', c(seq(1,19), 'X', 'Y')))

# BEGIN LOOP GENOME WINDOWS *** TIME CONSUMING ***
window.overlaps <- list()
ptm <- proc.time()
for(i in 1:100) { # ideally 1:length(chrY) but this takes very long so I've only posted a few windows
  result = feature.overlap(chrY, i, gene, extend.upstream=100000, extend.downstream=100000)
  window.overlaps[[i]] <- result
  progress(i)
}
proc.time() - ptm
all.overlaps = do.call(rbind, window.overlaps)
```

The code above will run right our of the box with [**this**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt4ay8rb77bq8ob/MEFES_K27AC.downsampled.sorted.wig?dl=0) file (88mb).

Here is my attempt to speed up the look using a `foreach` with the `doParallel` library:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)
ptm <- proc.time()
ls<-foreach(i = 1:100, chrY=chrY, gene=gene, .packages=c('rtracklayer', 'GenomicRanges')) %dopar% {
  result = feature.overlap(chrY, i, gene, extend.upstream=100000, extend.downstream=100000)
  progress(i)
  result
}
proc.time() - ptm
stopCluster(cl)
```

But, this codes does not work. The error returned is `Error: this S4 class is not subsettable` and no output is produced from `progress()`. **ERROR FIXED - SEE EDIT**

Again, the goal here is to write this in a more efficient manner. Once I have `values` I can easily compute the metrics I need.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT**: I've implement a working foreach loop with dopar, but it seems to be even slower than the above implementation.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)
ptm <- proc.time()
ls <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine='rbind', .packages=c('rtracklayer', 'GenomicRanges')) %dopar% { 
  result = feature.overlap(chrY, i, gene, counts, extend.upstream=100000, extend.downstream=100000)
  progress(i)
  result
}
proc.time() - ptm
stopCluster(cl)
```

For 100 windows this takes about 10 seconds whereas the same windows being processing with the for loop above takes 6 seconds.

Comment: Must the solutions make use of the foreach package or any parallel package can be used? Have you tried using the snowfall package which syntax is the same of the *apply family?

Comment: I have not tried the snowfall package but will look into it. Ideally I'd like to try to stick with the parallel package.

Comment: What is `idx`? Try using the same indices as the for loop because I think you may have some illegal accesses for `i = 1:100`.

Comment: I really hate Bioconductor packages. It's been 15 mins to install 3 packages. Some are more than 60MB. And `TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm9.knownGene`, is this really a package name?

Comment: You're using the wrong tools for this, as they are not optimized for set operations on this scale. Use BEDOPS: `bedops --everything --range 100000 foo.bed | bedops --element-of 1 genes.bed - > answer.bed`

Comment: And if you want to, you can parallelize easily by chromosome via a loop over `bedextract --list-chr foo.bed` and specifying the chromosome name as an option in the `bedops` commands. R is totally the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @F.Privé Yes its a package on bioconductor! I'm updating the code in the post so that it should run seamlessly.. but just slow...

Comment: @AlexReynolds The goal is to build a method that goes beyond what bedops can preform. This is one of the initial steps to doing so.

Comment: @F.Privé `idx` can actually simply be removed. Post is updated!

Comment: Have you looked at the relatively new package `biocParallel`? ("This package provides modified versions and novel implementation of functions for parallel evaluation, tailored to use with Bioconductor objects."). I've used it in a MOOC last year, forgot about the details.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I managed to run your code.

- For 100 runs, it takes

  - 6 sec with ncores = 1
  - 7 sec with ncores = 2
  - 8 sec with ncores = 3
  - 10 sec with ncores = 4
- For 1000 runs, it takes

  - 56 secs to run sequentially
  - 33 sec with 2 cores
  - 33 sec with 3 cores

So, basically, the 7 sec you see is due to overhead of parallelization. So the more you do, the more it will be useful to parallelize.

Then, what we can verify here, it is often inefficient to use more than half of the cores you have on your computer. So, if you have 8, you should use only 4.

Finally, if you have a very long loop, don't use the `.combine` parameter because it will take blocks of 100 and combine them, which is slow. If you can, just do a `Reduce` at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. `detectCores()` returns 8 so I've divided this in half and removed the `.combine` parameter. Here are my benchmarks:100 windows=6.443 seconds and 1000 windows=22.332 seconds. At this pace when I need to iterate over 1M windows, and we assume this scales linearly, it would still take 6+ hours. Is this the best I can do?

Comment: You will divide by 3-4 the running time by using parallelism. The rest you can do is to optimize your main function if you want to accelerate the computation :'). Try profiling it (the sequential one) and optimize the most computational parts.

Comment: IMO, using half available cores isn't always right. This guidance may come from that cores are often virtual cores with 2 virtual per physical. Utilization of these depends on the instructions. My  guidance is experiment and generally  always leave 1 core for the OS/UI.